# Elasticsearch startup error during SonarQube setup

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am trying to setup Sonarqube in my Macbook but I am getting following error when I try to start it with sh sonar.sh console

```
sudo sh sonar.sh console
Password:
/usr/bin/java
Running SonarQube...
Removed stale pid file: ./SonarQube.pid
 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /Applications/sonarqube/temp
 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:60506]
 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[ELASTICSEARCH] from [/Applications/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /Applications/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The Security Manager is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
    at java.base/java.lang.System.setSecurityManager(System.java:416)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.setSecurityManager(Security.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:70)
2022.08.24 16:24:52 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 1
2022.08.24 16:24:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2022.08.24 16:24:52 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

After some research on internet I have installed Java 11 but it is not helping me.

Comment: SonarqQube produces 4 logs. Look in the `es.log` for more details. Or one of the others.